# Смена минимального значения Ion.RangeSlider в зависимости от заданного значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Использую [Ion.RangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeslider/). Проблема в том, что есть несколько типов позиций, и в одной должно быть минимальное значение 1 000, а во второй - 10.

Дело в том, что не получается это сделать. Ion.RangeSlider я поместил в отдельную функцию, и вызываю в зависимости от присутствия data-атрибута в ссылке, по onclick которой он подтягивается:

```
if($(this).attr('data-immunity')){
    formRange(10);
}else{
    formRange(1000);
}
```

Сама функция:

```
function formRange(minSelect) {
    var minRange = minSelect;
    var maxRange = 10000;
    $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "single",
        min: minRange,
        max: maxRange,
        from: 4500,
        onChange: function (data) {
            var price =  $('#modal_form .per-1').val();
            $('.modal-price > span').html(parseFloat(data.from * price).toFixed(2));
        }
    });

}
```

Теперь если мы вызовем позицию, которая должно иметь минимальное значение 1000 -- установится значение 1000. Но оно не будет меняться при вызове позиции с минимальным значением 10. Также и в обратном порядке: если вызвать первой позицию с 10 -- всегда будет 10.

Сразу ответ на вопросы:

- В if-else входит, проверял
- В зависимости от выбора позиции аргумент 1000/10 передается в функцию
- Функция спокойно принимает аргументы и перезаписывает minRange
- Пробовал напрямую тянуть с value в `$("#range").ionRangeSlider({});` --тот же результат, хотя значение верное определяется(либо 1000, либо 10 в зависимости от позиции)

Comment: Приветствую! ;) А с каким событием у вас вот это ветвление срабатывает?
`if($(this).attr('data-immunity')){
    formRange(10);
}else{
    formRange(1000);
}`

Comment: @socode, `$(document).ready(function()` + `$('a.go').click( function(event)`.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
function formRange(minSelect) {
    var minRange = minSelect;
    var maxRange = 10000;
    return $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "single",
        min: minRange,
        max: maxRange,
        from: 4500,
        onChange: function (data) {
            var price =  $('#modal_form .per-1').val();
            $('.modal-price > span')
            .html(parseFloat(data.from * price).toFixed(2));
        }
    }).data("ionRangeSlider");
}    

$(".change-range").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).data('immunity') === true){
        formRange(10).update({from: 10});
    }else{
        formRange(1000).update({from: 1000});
    }
});
```